# Using delegate to create associated records in Rails 4 / Class or Multiple Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to build one model on top of another:

```
# This is a 'base' class which...
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :managers
end

# ...has managers, but they are just...
class Manager < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :person

  delegate :name, :email,
           to: :person

  validates_presence_of :position
end

# ...a 'layer' on top of a Person
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :manager

  validates_presence_of :name, :email
end
```

Because when you have managers, contact persons, clients, employees and so on, it's natural to make Person model to take care of the names, phones, emails and all the attributes that logically belong to person. It's like subclassing:

```
class PlanetDesigner < ActiveRecord::Base
# if it wasn't AR, we would use PlanetDesigner < Person...
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :what_not

  delegate :name, :email, #...but it's AR and we're using this instead
           to: :person

  # here go lots of PlanetDesigner-specific methods
end

class SaviourOfTheUniverse < ActiveRecord::Base
  # same scenario here
end

# and a few similar classes more
```

But how?

When I `Company.find(42).managers.create(name: 'Slartibartfast', email: 'vip_planets@magrathea.com', position: 'Designer')`, I expectedly get `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: name`.

I sure can do it with callbacks and stuff, but tell me, can't Rails do it itself?

To me this is not the case of a polymorphic association. It's having several different models with different behaviour and their own attributes built on top of Person.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: May be you should give `Person.find(42).manager.create(name: 'Slartibartfast', email: 'vip_planets@magrathea.com', position: 'Designer')`.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but why not use Single Table Inheritance instead? It sounds like a `Person` is a `Manager` with only one column different, no? Either that, or a polymorphic relationship.

Comment: I've just updated my question to make it more clear, pls. re-read. Thank you.

Comment: Very nice names, awesome!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Manager < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :person

  delegate :name, :email, to: :person

  validates_presence_of :position

  accepts_nested_attribute_for :person
end

Company.find(42).managers.create(position: 'Designer', person_attributes: {
  name: 'Slartibartfast', email: 'vip_planets@magrathea.com', 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

After some additional research I figured that the answer to my question is obvious and it's called Multiple Table Inheritance (MTI) or Class Table Inheritance (CTI).

One particular solution is [ActiveRecord::ActsAs gem](https://github.com/hzamani/active_record-acts_as) written by Hassan Zamani, which is probably the most elegant and up-to-date. I've checked out [every other alternative from Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=multiple%20table%20inheritance) and they all seem either abandoned or outdated.

It bugs me though why there's no native support for CTI in Rails yet, as the problem is so common. A few searches in Google and ruby-forum.com showed no active discussions about implementing the feature.

I thank everyone for their answers and the time taken.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to extract naming logic from `Manager`, you can do smth like that:

```
class Manager < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company

  def person
    @person ||= Person.new(name, email)
  end
end

# plain Ruby class
class Person
  def initialize(name, email)
    @name, @email = name, email
  end
  # person methods
end

# and then use it:
Manager.find(42).person.name_with_mail
```